# How to work and update nested, sortable records

Tags: python, mysql, nested, treeview

How to work with nested, sortable records

I'm not a developer, but I'm trying to achieve some new skills. I have little experience with PHP, let's say I've created few small apps already and they work pretty well.

As my job is mainly working with Linux Systems, I decided to learn python and change my focus as it can help me for web as well as scripting for automation etc...

So here is what I'm currently trying to achieve.

The task:

We have some regular events where multiple teams have to participate and work on different tasks, one team might need to complete a task that is blocking other team to start part of their things...

That said I need to create something like live multiplayer ToDo app updated realtime and tasks are nested and sorted the proper way.

Example would look like this:

```
Main Taks
|
|-> Child task ---------------------------------------- [action button][action button][...]
|      |-> Child of the child task -------------------- [action button][action button][...]
|          |-> etc... --------------------------------- [action button][action button][...]
|-> Another child task -------------------------------- [action button][action button][...]
|   |-> Another nested child -------------------------- [action button][action button][...]
|-> Another child task -------------------------------- [action button][action button][...]
etc...
```

I'm thinking of creating a backend API using python, and I guess vuejs or react for the front end as it needs to be realtime.

Digging through articles and howtos I found the proper way to structure my database table so I can have unlimited nesting:

```
----------------------------------
| id | parent_id | order | etc.. |
----------------------------------
```

So pretty much I can have incremental id, then the parent id could be 0 for the root and relative id for the parent. 
I have the order as well so with recursive function in python I can generate a nice json to send to frontend.

My problem is, how to work with re-ordering the tree?
I really can't figure out how to perform this. Like from the example that I provided, how can I properly move the last "Another child task" to be as 4th level and child of the "Child of the child task".
Also all childs must be in percise order as they need to be performed in strict order.

I want this to be drag and droppable. Still learning javascript but I found a lot ready to go solutions that look pretty cool. I just can't figure out how to update the order of all the childs...

I guess the language is not that important, mostly the logic that has to be implemented.

What should I send from frontend when something on the tree changes and how to process this on the backend....

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I still haven't done much. I initially tried with PHP but then realized I would do it with python using Flask. Currently still learning Python/Flask. It's like those projects where you do something while you learn and at the end you get something that you could use in real life. Currently I have written only the route and mechanism to fetch all tasks and return them as json:

Note: I'm using SQLAlchemy

```
class TreeView(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    order = db.Column(db.Integer)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200))
```

That;s the DB model

```
def todo():

    output = []
    records = TreeView.query.all()
    for record in records:
        robj = {}
        robj['id'] = record.id
        robj['parent_id'] = record.parent_id
        robj['order'] = record.order
        robj['name'] = record.name
        output.append(robj)

    return jsonify(output)
```

That's the query and return json.

Currently checking vuejs with examples how I need to nest the json so it's properly formatted to be digested by the nested tree.

The main blocker for me though is to work out how to really sort things especially when updating.

Comment: Welcome to SO . can you provide some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: THats a great start.. You won;t get much help here without code to look at.. Even if it is a mix of code and Pseudo code or a comment of `# need to find x here.`, you will get help..

Comment: I can recommend FastApi for creating APIs in Python.  They have some good examples as well, docker stacks, and front / backend examples.

Comment: Sry, will try better next time :D

Comment: Sry for my non complete answer the first time. And thank you for reading my question at all. Still not really familiar with SO's interface. I've red a lot in it but never posted and didn't expect enter to submit, then I tried to edit and add more, and the characters were more then the limit so I updated the question itself. Looks like comments cannot be that extensive. I guess I messed it up. I will build the most of it and when I have more code I can come back and update. The problem is that I got no f**g clue how to approach the update part :(

Comment: I decided to go with Flask as it's something that can be used for simple pages as well instead of just APIs so I liked the idea to learn something that can help for other things as well.